# The first "if condition" does not work. Help please?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am trying to build a binary tree program with user interaction.The user can input numbers.And the binary tree will be built graphically.The purpose of the first if condition is not to allow the user to enter the same number twice. But it is not working

```
input_num.restrict="0-9";
input_num.maxChars = 3;

AddButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clicked);

function clicked(event_object:MouseEvent) 
{
    var check:Boolean;
    check==false;

    if(check==true)
        {
        output_text.text="works"
        }
    else if(input_num.text=="")
        {
        output_text.text="Field can not be empty"
        }
    else
        {
        output_text.text=""
        var number=Number(input_num.text);
        output_text.text="You entered "+number+""
        check==true;

        var root=number;

        var newCircle:Shape = new Shape();
        newCircle.graphics.lineStyle(4, 0x6D00D9);
        newCircle.graphics.beginFill(0xff005E);
        newCircle.graphics.drawEllipse(x+225.9, y+68.0, 40, 40);
        newCircle.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(newCircle);

        var tf:TextField = new TextField();
        var style:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        style.bold=true;
        style.size=24;
        style.color=0xFFFF33;
        tf.text = root.toString();
        tf.x = x+236.9;
        tf.y = y+73.0;
        addChild(tf);
        tf.setTextFormat(style);
        }
}
```

Comment: When you said it's not working, do you get an error or the IF is *by-passed*?

Comment: No I do not get any error. The first if condition just does not work

Answer (score 2):

First, as Tezirg points out, you need to create the variable `check` *outside* of your function. By creating it in the function, it's scope is limited to the function, and it no longer exists when the function is complete. The `check` you're looking at the second time the function runs is a *different* variable. You can read more about function scope [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f54.html).

Secondly,

```
check==true;
```

is a comparison, not an assignment, so it doesn't do anything. You need:

```
check = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time your method is called, the variables in the scope a re-built, so indeed your check var is always false when it is used by the first condition.
I don't know about action script but I guess that what your a seeking is a "static variable".

Comment: But I make the check var variable true in the button click event.So then the if condition should work right ?

Comment: Yes if you're still in your function, but if you are calling the same function a second time your $check will be set to true as you are asiking it at the line  

   var check:Boolean;
   check==false;

Answer (score 0):

As already said, don't define your `check` variable inside your function if you want it to keep its value at each call.

Then you should replace

```
var check:Boolean;
check==false;
```

by

```
var check:Boolean = false;
```

to assign a value to `check` (the same for `check == true` as pointed out by David Mear). Moreover

```
if ( check==true )
```

is correct, but you can write

```
if (check)
```

because `check == true` is `true` when the value of `check` is `true`… so it is equivalent to `check`.